# .htaccess is not getting the url in php

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite URL using `.htaccess` file but it is not getting the URL. My `.htaccess` file is this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1
```

`routs.php` file is this where I want to get the URL.

```
  if(isset($_GET['url']))
   {
        $url=$_GET['url'];
        $url=rtrim($url,'/');
```

but its not working properly

Comment: `rout` is "a disorderly retreat of defeated troops." . Just saying.

Comment: what is the evidence of "not working properly"?

Comment: So is the name of the file containing the code `index.php` or `routs.php`? What URL did you type in? Does the URL point to an existing file?

Comment: yes it piont to existing file that is placed in the layout.php file

Comment: Your question is unclear, please describe what files are involved, what URL you call and which file you expect to be executed. The `!` in the rewrite condition means a `not`, that translates to: `call index.php if the url is not an existing directory and not an existing file`. Is this what you want?